# How to get link status using netlink in polling mode?

Tags: linux-kernel, netlink

Is it possible to use netlink api to get link status immediately (without waiting when kernel throws the message)? I used ioctl SIOCGIFFLAGS for getting the status of the link. Is it possible to do the same with netlink or it's complete event-based mechanism? All of the examples I could find used recvmsg() with wile() loop or select() -   all these are event-driven methods, but I need asynchronous method. My pseudo code for netlink would be like that:

```
int fd = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE);
bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&local_addr, sizeof(local_addr));

//send some message so the kernel responded with the answer (which contains link status) 
ssize_t result = sendmsg(fd, &msg, ...);

//reading the answer
ssize_t result = recvmsg(fd, &msg, MSG_DONTWAIT);

//parsing the message to get link status
```

Is it possible with netlink api? Thanks!